# Как через выбранный option добавить атрибут select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Есть два списка с адресами. И необходимо при выборе одного из адреса, родительскому select добавить атрибут name. Подскажите, пожалуйста , как это сделать?

Теоретически понимаю. Выбранному дать selected и через parent() назначить атрибут, но на коде не получается.

Comment: что значит "родительскому select"? то есть при выборе одного селекта, добавлять другому свойство?

Comment: не совсем. Два списка  <select1> <option1><option2></select>  и второй <select2> <option3> <option4></select> . И если выбран option4 например то именно select2 добавить определенный атрибут

Comment: тогда покажите код, чтобы мы поняли о чем идет речь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('change', '.select', function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'option4') {
    $(this).attr('name', 'select_name');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option selected disabled>Выберите</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="select">
  <option selected disabled>Выберите</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```